# Есть ли смысл хешировать CSRF-токен?

Tags: хеширование, csrf

Для подтверждения того, что форма была отправлена именно пользователем, используется такой механизм: при отправке страницы пользователю устанавливается Cookie со случайным значением и то же значение встраивается в hidden-поле в HTML-форме. Если такая операция уже производилась (Cookie-токен уже установлен), значение для скрытого поля берётся из него. При получении запроса сервер сверяет значения Cookie и скрытого поля.

Есть ли смысл записывать в скрытое поле хешированное значение? То есть, повысит ли это безопасность в целом?

И безопасна ли сама схема? Токен с момента установки в Cookie не изменяется.

Comment: Если пользователь откроет 2 вкладки, первая из них будет невалидная, так как в Cookie будет значение с другой вкладки.

Comment: @Zergatul, Cookie не меняется с момента установки. Забыл написать, что если Cookie существует, значение для скрытого поля берём из него.

Comment: @Zergatul, но теперь понял, что записывать в Cookie хеш не имеет смысла.